# Faut-il écrire "Je t'envoies" ou bien "Je t'envoie" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, conjugaison

Dans la phrase suivante:

> Je t'envoies ce mail suite à [...]

Je me suis demandé si il fallait écrire "Je t'envoies" ou bien "Je t'envoie"

J'ai donc effectué quelques recherches, et d'après [The-conjugation.com](https://www.the-conjugation.com/french/verb/s_envoyer.php):

> **Présent de l'indicatif**
>
> je m'envoie
>   tu t'envoies
>   il s'envoie
>   nous nous envoyons
>   vous vous envoyez
>   ils s'envoient

Or cela ne m'as pas réellement aidé à répondre à ma question car le conjugeur n'utilise que "je m'envoie" ou "tu t'envoies" mais pas "Je t'envoies".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un verbe s'accorde avec son sujet et le sujet est un pronom à la première personne du singulier (je), il n'y a donc pas de *s*  :

> Je t'envoie

c'est à dire:

> J'envoie à toi

*Te* est ici le complément d'objet indirect du verbe *envoyer*.

Le site indique la conjugaison d'envoyer à la forme pronominale (s'envoyer à soi), ce qui n'est pas celle utilisée ici, mais accorde bien sûr toujours *envoyer* avec son sujet.

Answer (score 0):

Dans cette phrase le sujet est "je", ou "j'", donc le verbe se conjugue à la première personne du singulier.

Je comprends que le complément d'objet indirect (COI) puisse induire en erreur (puisqu'il y a un "t'" ou un "tu", ne devrais-je pas ajouter un s?), mais en Français la conjugaison du présent tient uniquement compte du sujet.

Quand on peut répondre à "à qui est-ce que j'envoie" par "je t'envoie ceci", alors "t'" est un COI et ne joue pas de rôle dans la conjugaison du verbe.